# Regex for university emails

Tags: java, regex

I am looking to validate email addresses by making sure they have a specific university subdomain, e.g. if the user says they attend Oxford University, I want to check that their email ends in .ox.ac.uk

If I have the '.ox.ac.uk' part stored as a variable, how can I incorporate this with a regex to check the whole email is valid and ends in that variable suffix?

Many thanks!

Comment: What's the value of this check, and are you sure it outweighs the nuisance factor for users who prefer to use their `gmail.com` account or whatever?

Answer (score 3):

We are using this email pattern (derived from this [regular-expressions.info article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)):

```
^[\w!#$%&'*+/=?^`{|}~-]+(?:\.[\w!#$%&'*+/=?^`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$`
```

You should be able to extend it with your needed suffix:

```
^[\w!#$%&'*+/=?^`{|}~-]+(?:\.[\w!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:\.ox\.ac\.uk)$`
```

Note that I replaced the TLD part `[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?` with your required suffix `(?:\.ox\.ac\.uk)` (`\.` is used to match the dot only)

Edit: one additional note: if you use `String#matches(...)` or `Matcher#matches()` there's no need for the leading ^ and the trailing $, since the entire string would have to match anyways.

Comment: @Jonny yes, we keep that regex in our db, that's why there's no \\ in the example. In a Java String you'd escape all those back slashes :)

Comment: I'm using 
String expression = "^[\\w!#$%&'*+/=?^`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[\\w!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\\.)+(?:\\.ox\\.ac\\.uk)$`";

as you suggested, but it doesn't seem to be matching ok, as it says it's failing on the input myname@ox.ac.uk, for which it should succeed

Comment: @Jonny you said the suffix was `.ox.ac.uk` so I assumed there was something between the @ and the suffix. However, your test email address ends with `@ox.ac.uk` so it would not match.

Comment: @Jonny In order to match addresses only ending in `@ox.ac.uk` change the expression to `[\\w!#$%&'*+/=?^{|}~-]+(?:\\.[\\w!#$%&'*+/=?{|}~-]+)*@(?:\\.ox\\.ac\\.uk)`

Comment: Why not just use the regex to check that the e-mail is a valid address and then use String.endsWith(".ox.ac.uk")?

Comment: @Lauri the regex I posted initially actually checks if the email address is valid (according to RFC 2822, with some uncommon parts left out). The change adds the `endsWith` logic to that regex, reducing some complexity at the end. The problem ist just the definition of what is valid: `...@ox.ac.uk` only or `...@something.ox.ac.uk` as well? The OP did state the latter but tested for the first variant.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using php.

```
$ending = '.ox.ac.uk';
if(preg_match('/'.preg_quote($ending).'$/i', $email_address)) //... your code
```

Further info: the preg_quote() is necessary so that characters get escaped if they have a special meaning. In your case it's the dots.

edit: To check if the *whole email is valid*, see other questions, it is asked a lot. Just wanted to help with your special case.

Comment: Many thanks!

I'm actually using java but I'll have a go at converting it over :)